# Php mysql checkbox arrays

Tags: php, mysql

Below is my HTML FORM:

```
<input name="gen[10]" type="checkbox" id="no2" value="10" />:11-20<br/>
<input name="gen[20]" type="checkbox" id="no3" value="20" />:21-30<br/>
<input name="gen[30]" type="checkbox" id="no4" value="30" />:31-40<br/>
<input name="gen[40]" type="checkbox" id="no5" value="40" />:41-50<br/>
<input name="gen[50]" type="checkbox" id="no6" value="50" />:51-60<br/>
<input name="gen[60]" type="checkbox" id="no7" value="60" />:61-70<br/>
<input name="gen[70]" type="checkbox" id="no8" value="70" />:71-80<br/>
<input name="gen[80]" type="checkbox" id="no9" value="80" />:81-90<br/>
```

My Database(mysql) has a table with 2 fields , number and frequency

My PHP:

```
foreach($_POST['gen'] as $option_key => $gen)
{

            $query = "SELECT number FROM frequency ORDER BY frequency DESC LIMIT $gen,10";
            $result = mysql_query($query);
            echo $query;

                if (mysql_affected_rows() > 0)
                    {
                        while($row = mysql_fetch_array($result))
                            {
                                echo $row['number'];
                                echo "&nbsp;";
                            }
                    }
                }


}
```

I am trying to select numbers from my table based on their frequency, e:g can be seen on http://www.luckynumbers.co.zw/generator.aspx

I should be able to make multiple selections on my checkboxes and it should select from my table based on all my selections.

I hope I explained well, thank you

Comment: You are allowing people to hack you using SQL injection. Please *at least* escape your input variables. [**ALso, don't use `mysql_*` functions in new code**](http://bit.ly/phpmsql). They are no longer maintained [and are officially deprecated](https://wiki.php.net/rfc/mysql_deprecation). See the [**red box**](http://j.mp/Te9zIL)? Learn about [*prepared statements*](http://j.mp/T9hLWi) instead, and use [PDO](http://php.net/pdo) or [MySQLi](http://php.net/mysqli) - [this article](http://j.mp/QEx8IB) will help you decide which. If you choose PDO, [here is a good tutorial](http://j.mp/PoWehJ).

Comment: Why you don't just name your inputs all name="gen[]"?

Comment: Yes i jus did gen[] seems to work, thanks.

Comment: I need the returned values to placed in an array?